# Unable to remove secondary ip address on Debian 11 interface

Tags: linux, debian, network-interface

I have a Debian 11 installed on an Intel NUC with Wireless configured with static ip address.

For whatever reason, The wlan0 interface gets a secondary IP address which I cannot remove. I tried ip addr del ... or flush. As soon as I enter that command, networking freeze (it's a headless through SSH). I tried `ip addr del 172.30.47.199/23 dev wlan0 && service networking restart`, but it never comes back and I have to reboot. And after reboot, primary and secondary IPs are back.

I cannot find any running service which would be responsible to assign this address to that interface. NetworkManager, dhcpcd do not seem to be running at all. Obviously, I checked `interfaces.d` folder and other networking folders, and they are empty.

I also tried 'dhclient -r'. This makes it freeze, same was as ip addr del, and I have to reboot. None of this make sens... After rebooting, I checked journal for dhclient and I find this:

```
Feb 25 01:54:39 ds9 ifdown[8114]: dhclient.c:2879: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
Feb 25 01:54:39 ds9 dhclient[8114]: dhclient.c:2879: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over fallback interface.
```

The DHCP server runs in a container on that same machine. But the fact network stop working because I run `dhclient -r` while the machine has a static IP address anyway is confusing me totally. It has a static IP, yet if I remove the secondary IP (DHCP assigned), it stops responding.... This could be related to the route being deleted when the secondary IP is removed. Still thou: Why is that secondary IP assigned.

At this point, I'm out of idea. I hit my incompetency level.

Content of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 172.30.46.1
        netmask 255.255.254.0
    gateway 172.30.47.1
```

`ip addr show wlan0` returns:

```
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:c5:89:55:32:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.30.46.1/23 brd 172.30.47.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.30.47.199/23 scope global secondary noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`systemctl list-units --type=service --state=running` returns:

```
  UNIT                        LOAD   ACTIVE SUB     DESCRIPTION
  bluetooth.service           loaded active running Bluetooth service
  containerd.service          loaded active running containerd container runtime
  cron.service                loaded active running Regular background program processing daemon
  dbus.service                loaded active running D-Bus System Message Bus
  ddclient.service            loaded active running Update dynamic domain name service entries
  docker.service              loaded active running Docker Application Container Engine
  getty@tty1.service          loaded active running Getty on tty1
  iwd.service                 loaded active running Wireless service
  rsyslog.service             loaded active running System Logging Service
  ssh.service                 loaded active running OpenBSD Secure Shell server
  systemd-journald.service    loaded active running Journal Service
  systemd-logind.service      loaded active running User Login Management
  systemd-timesyncd.service   loaded active running Network Time Synchronization
  systemd-udevd.service       loaded active running Rule-based Manager for Device Events and Files
  unattended-upgrades.service loaded active running Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
  user@1000.service           loaded active running User Manager for UID 1000
```

I checked [this discussion in Raspberry Pi site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13359/where-does-my-secondary-ip-come-from), but it doesn't offer a solution.

New lead: If docker is disabled at boot, no secondary IP is assigned. My guess is one of the container makes a dhclient call on host mode network. I have to find out which one. Would most probably solve the issue. But I don't know if there is an easy way to isolate that container or if I have to go through all of them to hopefully find out

Comment: SE sites aren't discussion forums, these work differently. Instead of adding new info, answers to questions or testing results as comments it's better to [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736794/edit) your initial question. That way it gets more focused, stays up-to-date with your situation and everything relevant is immediately available. I added these comments for you, my edit will become visible when approved by another member of the community :-) When it does I'd suggest deleting these comments to leave room for others - extended threads are hard to follow. I'm deleting mine.